# How can I mix higher-kinds with "regular" generics for Typeclasses in Scala

Tags: scala, generics, typeclass, higher-kinded-types

I'm trying to write my own Typeclass in scala, to provide a mechanism to convert classes into an arbitrary "DataObject" (for which I'm using a Map below, however I don't want that to be important). Up until now I have the following:

```
type DataObject = Map[String, Any]

trait DataSerializer[A] {
    def toDataObject(instance: A): DataObject
    def fromDataObject(dataObject: DataObject): A
}
```

This works well for 'simple' classes, for which I can create a concrete class implementing this trait to act as my serializer. However, I thought it would also be nice to allow Collections/Containers to be serialized, without having to create a different implementation for every type that could be contained. I ended up with this:

```
trait DataCollectionSerializer[Collection[_]] {
    def toDataObject[A: DataSerializer](instance: Collection[A]): DataObject
    def fromDataObject[A: DataSerializer](dataObject: DataObject): Collection[A]
}
```

ie. a collection can be serialized if it's contents can be serialized.

Again, this works well for most things, but what if I have a collection within a collection? For example, `List[List[Int]]` (assuming that there exists some implementation of `DataCollectionSerializer[List]` and `DataSerializer[Int]`) would require an implementation of `DataSerializer[List[Int]]`. I could simply continue writing a new trait for each level of containment, however that would eventually result in some upper limit for what my Typeclass could achieve.

Is there some way that I could combine these two traits, to allow `DataCollectionSerializer` to operate upon any collection, providing its contents have either a `DataSerializer` or `DataCollectionSerializer`?

Answer (score 0):

You can change `DataCollectionSerializer` to

```
trait DataCollectionSerializer[Collection[_]] {
  def serializer[A: DataSerializer]: DataSerializer[Collection[A]]
}
```

and to get `DataSerializer` for e.g. `List[Int]`: `implicitly[DataCollectionSerializer[List]].serializer[Int]`. Then all non-higher-kind types have a `DataSerializer` and you don't need to mix anything.

Comment: I was hoping that there would be some way that I could have a `ListSerializer extends DataCollectionSerializer[List]` and `DataSerializer[Int]`, which could be combined to deal with `List[List[ ... List[Int] ... ]]` without some special class to deal with the intermediary collections. In that way I could transform to/from the serialized form using a recursive method.However, it doesn't appear that I can do this without explicitly providing something for each step; as the method could potentially require an arbitrary number of serializers to be included from the context.